# Source code to round floating point number

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Other than using any inbuilt function like `ceil` and `floor` how can you round a floating point number?

I want to convert 2.10 to 2.14-> 2.1 and 2.15 to 2.19 -> 2.2

I wrote some logic but stuck in the middle

```
    float a = 2.24;
    int b = a*100;
    int result n, i =0;
    while(i>2)
    {
        n = b%10;
        i++;
    }
    if(n >5)
    {
      c = b%10;
      c = c/10 + 1;
    }
```

I tried lot of inbuild function but all that not workign for my diab compiler

```
//  totalDist = roundf(totalDist * 10) / 10.0;      
//  totalDist = floor(totalDist * pow(10., 1) + .5) / pow(10., 1);  
    totalDist = floorf(totalDist * 10 + 0.5) / 10;
```

planning to write my own logic

Comment: Why "Other than using any inbuilt function"?

Comment: `totalDist = floorf(totalDist * 10 + 0.5) / 10;` seem to be correct one, except you're could use float type literals: `10.0f` and `0.5f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because my old answer needs lot of careful programming to make it work

### I present another way to implement an round function:

You can easily check if a (positive/negative) number will be rounded up
or down by (adding/subtracting) 0.5. Then you can truncate the result
and take your answer. Also, in order to support deeper level of round as
you want you can let the user specify how many decimal places of round
the want, and voila:

```
long double round_f(long double number, int decimal_places)
{
     assert(decimal_places > 0);

     double power = pow(10, decimal_places-1);
     number *= power;

     return (number >= 0) ? ((long long)(number + 0.5))/power : ((long long)(number - 0.5))/power;
}
```

[And here you can see a working example.](http://ideone.com/9Lew2h)

## Old one:

You can use sprint:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float a = 2.24;
    int size;
    char num[8] = {0};
    sprintf(num, "%d", (int) (a * 100));

    for (size=0; num[size]; size++);

    size--;

    if (num[size] < '5') {
        num[size] = '0';
    } else {
        num[size] = '0';
        if (num[size-1] == '9')
            num[size-1] = '0';
        else
            num[size-1]++;
    }

    printf("a = %f\n", a);
    printf("num = %s\n", num);

    return(0);
}
```

You can see the logic. Finally you can revert the string to integer and multiply by 100.

**EDIT:** It's only the logic. See comments below for what is needed to fully work.

Comment: Final numner is 220, actial result expected is 2.3

Comment: This method fails for `a > 100000.0`.  It fails for numbers like `3.99`.  It fails `a < -10000.0`.  It fails for `a*100` outsize `int` range.

Comment: Yeah. i know that. I only wanted to show the logic behind it. You can easily replace the nested if which checks for 9 with a loop. You can also make bigger the character array fr bigger numbers. You can also leave the first position empty to avoid "overflow" (for the carry in a case like 99.99).

Comment: Agree that this is a general demonstration of the logic behind an approach and not a complete solution: (float --> int --> sprintf --> char processing --> covert back to float).  Asserting it is "can easily replace", yet not posting that belies the subtle issues: limited `int` range, char buffer overflow, arithmetic overflow handling.

Comment: @chux I changed my answer to meet your criteria I believe. What's your opinion? Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @gon1332 I think it would be better to revert to the earlier accepted answer.  Using `int`, which may only have a range of -32767 to 32767 is vary limiting.  Even using `long long` is limiting when input is a `long double`.

Answer (score 3):

```
float a = 2.24;
float b = roundf(a*10.0f)/10.0f;//roundf in C99
```

Comment: +1 For a solution that 1) works with both positive & negative numbers, 2) is not limited to `int` range and 3) is precise.  (Suggest 10.0f instead of 10.0).

Comment: @chux I changed according to your proposal.

Comment: @Kerrek SB I used to think that too.  My review of C spec did not find support of that.  It appears to depend on `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.  If it is 0, then "evaluate all operations and constants just to the range and precision of the type;"  If 1, then "evaluate operations and constants of type float and double to the range and precision of the double type ...".  Other settings exist.

Comment: @chux: You're right, never mind - the arithmetic conversions allow for both operands to be floats.

Answer (score 1):

Try `int((x + 0.05) * 10.0) / 10.0`.

You can also use [`trunc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/trunc) instead of the conversion to and from `int`.

Or you could use [`round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round): `round(x * 10.0) / 10.0`

Comment: `int()` will fail ouside integer range. `trunc()` will fail on negative numbers. You could use `floor()` instead.

Comment: @Vovanium: Outside the integer range, floats also won't have sub-unit precision. OP didn't specify behaviour for negative numbers, but that's indeed something to be decided.

Comment: First, standard defines least integer range as -32767..32767 which is less than most available float precision. Second, even for large numbers (e.g. 1E10) rounding isn't possible function could return right value, not overflown one.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to round the number for output purposes, then the `%.1f` format string is indeed the correct answer.

```
printf("%.1f", 2.14);
```

or 
If you actually want to round off value then something like this work

```
#include <math.h>

float val = 37.777779;

float rounded_down = floorf(val * 100) / 100;   /* Result: 37.77 */
float nearest = floorf(val * 100 + 0.5) / 100;  /* Result: 37.78 */
float rounded_up = ceilf(val * 100) / 100;      /* Result: 37.78 */
```

Usually we use `nearest` method

Comment: Note: `floorf(val * 100 + 0.5)` fails for negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

BLUEPIXY's answer is good. But in general; floating point multiplication is faster than division, so if speed is relevant; multiply by 0.1 instead of dividing by 10.

Comment: I tried all these


 // totalDist = roundf(totalDist * 10) / 10.0;   
 // totalDist = floor(totalDist * pow(10., 1) + .5) / pow(10., 1); 
  totalDist = floorf(totalDist * 10 + 0.5) / 10;